# Is there a definitive answer as to the identity of the Hybrid?

Tags: doctor-who

The finale of series nine made several alternative suggestions as to who the Hybrid is. It posits Clara and Me as possible Hybrids. On more than one occasion the Doctor claims to be the Hybrid.

However, nothing seems to be definitive. It's all very cloak and dagger, seemingly left up to the viewer's discretion to draw their own conclusions.

**Is there a definitive answer in canon as to who the Matrix Prophesies were talking about? Or as to if the Hybrid is even real?**

Comment: Does the Doctor actually claim to be the hybrid, or does he say "the hybrid is Me?"

Comment: He says it at the end of Heaven Sent and also at the end of Hell Bent. "I went too far, I became the Hybrid" or words to that effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is *no* - it was not made absolutely clear.

The Timelords believed in a prophecy about 'The Hybrid', "a creature thought to be crossbred from two warrior races". The prophecy stated that the creature "will one day stand in the ruins of Gallifrey. It will unravel the Web of Time and destroy a billion, billion hearts to heal its own".

The show put forward 3 possibilities of who/what 'The Hybrid' might be:

1. **Ashildr/Me** - part human, part Mire (after the Doctor brought her back to life with Mire tech)
2. **The Doctor** - *possibly* part Timelord, part human (the Eighth Doctor TV movie suggested this was the case, and Ashildr/Me also alluded to it, suggesting that The Doctor might be The Hybrid and questioning why he spent so much time on earth. The Doctor did not refute this)
3. **The Doctor *and* Clara** - this was another of Ashildr's theories, suggesting The Hybrid might be "a dangerous combination of a passionate and powerful Time Lord and a young woman so very similar to him".

The Doctor dismissed the Time Lord's belief that it might be a Dalek/Timelord hybrid as an "assumption". Also, no such creature has ever appeared.

Of the three possibilities stated above, only The Doctor came close to actually fulfilling the details of the prophecy:

1. *He stood in the ruins of Gallifrey*. The planet had been lost since the Time War, so when The Doctor returned to it in this episode it was arguably in a ruined, post-war state.
2. *He 'unravelled the Web of Time'* by permanently removing Clara from a fixed moment in time (her death). The Time Lords warned him that this could "fracture Time itself" by doing so.
3. *He risked (but didn't destroy) a billion, billion hearts to heal its own*. He saved Clara from her death because of his attachment to her, but he did put time itself (and all the billion, billions of lives in it) in danger. Of course, things turned out okay.

However, there is strong evidence within the episode to suggest that we are not meant to discover who or what The Hybrid is - in fact, the entire plot device may be an allegory showing the folly of prophecies, and there may be no hybrid at all. When discussing the prophecy with the Timelords, The Doctor asked them what other details the prophecy contained, and he scoffed at the lack of detail, saying "*prophecies, they never tell you anything useful, do they?*" The fact that The Doctor and his companions could concoct three different possibilities that fit the prophecy (as well as the Timelords belief that it could be a Dalek/Timelord hybrid) shows that details can be twisted to fit vague prophecies. The two interconnected episodes (*Heaven Sent / Hell Bent*) show the pain, suffering and confusion that arises from people following the prophecy.

Comment: IIRC, there was some indication that the hybrid would be half Timelord, half Dalek. And there were more then a few Daleks that said to the Doctor "you would have made a good Dalek/you *are* a good Dalek". A Timelord by Biology and a Dalek in mind, could be what the Hybrid is.

Comment: @Christopher The idea that it definitely was a dalek/timelord was dismissed by the Doctor, though. What you mention, that the Daleks suggested The Doctor was *as ruthless* as a Dalek, is more of an insult or indictment against the Doctor, that he hadn't behaved as benevolently as he thinks he is. It is stretching the concept of what a 'hybrid' is, which the Doctor/Clara combo does, too, but at least it was presented in that episode as something that had reached Gallifrey and was a possibility.

Answer (score 7):

From *Doctor Who Magazine* issue #504, in the section that allows fans to ask the then showrunner Steven Moffat their questions, he has this to say:

> FINLAY WORRALLO asks: Why did the TARDIS dislike Clara?
>
> The TARDIS, being aware of all time simultaneously, was also aware that Clara was the precise motivator that would drive the Doctor to an extreme that was dangerous for all time and space. She knew, that although the Doctor loved her very much, she was bad for him and that the coming of the Hybrid would be the result of their association.

From this, it could be inferred that the association of the Doctor and Clara together form the Hybrid. Time Lords and Humans are both referred to as warrior races in the episode (see the ending dialogue between Me and the Doctor), which would fit the Hybrid's description. The billions of hearts they would break would presumably be the billions that would die if

> Clara was kept from dying, her death being a fixed point, and preventing fixed points tears the universe apart (see *The Wedding of River Song*).

Comment: I've seen the wiki. Can you provide the original source for this quote. A Doctor-Clara pairing makes no sense so I'd need to see something to back this up for me to accept.

Comment: @The Dark Lord I managed to track down the source of the wiki's section on the origin of the Hybrid, hope this helps! Still in inference rather than a definitive "*X* (or *X* and *Y*) is the Hybrid", but I think this is the best answer available with current information.

Comment: You could also interpret the billions of hearts as belonging to the billions of instances of the Doctor who died in the confession dial.

Comment: @AJM That's a really great spin on it actually, never thought about that!

Answer (score -3):

It turns out the hybrid is Ashildr who lives to the end of space time

https://www.quora.com/Doctor-Who-TV-series-Who-is-the-hybrid

Comment: Could you [edit] in the relevant information from the link in case it does and any supporting evidence such as quotes?